# How do I get $(this) two levels deep?

Tags: jquery

alright so I'm trying to set up a keydown dispatcher that will do different things based on which key was pressed.

It's added to onkeyup on my input field

```
$(function() {
  $("#myInput").keyup(suggestion_dispatcher);
});
```

and then this is the suggestion dispatcher itself

```
function suggestion_dispatcher() {
    alert($(this).val());
    var code = event.which;

    if(code == 13) {
        // select
    } else if (code == 38) {
        // up
    } else if (code == 40) {
        // down
    } else {
        $.proxy(get_suggestion(), $(this));
    }
}
```

Even using the jQuery proxy, inside my get_suggestion() function if I look at `this` or `$(this)` I see that it's giving me the window object instead of the input box that's being typed into.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try this : `get_suggestion.apply(this);` or `get_suggestion.call(this);`.

Here is some useful reference - http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: You're a lifesaver.  That worked.  I'll accept as soon as I can.